# Take any single record if matching records not available - Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have linq query which has multiple records & I am filtering these records using a `where` clause.

Now, if the filtered records return nothing then I need to make it default to take default *any single* record from list.

```
var resultStaffGua = (from s in _db.Students
 join sg in _db.StudentStaffGuardians on s.StudentID equals sg.StudentId
 join g in _db.Staffs on sg.StaffId equals g.StaffID
 join lr in _db.luRelationTypes on sg.RelationTypeId equals lr.RelationTypeID
 join ga in _db.StaffAddresses on g.StaffID equals ga.StaffID
 join ad in _db.Addresses on ga.AddressID equals ad.AddressID
 where
 lse.StatusID == (int?)Extension.StatusType.Active 
 && lse.TenantID == tenantid
 select new
 {
     g.FirstName,
     g.LastName,
     IsPrimary = sg.IsPrimaryGuardian,
     se.Email,
     Phone = sphon.PhoneNumber,
     lr.RelationCD,
     gdnr.GenderCD,
     ad.Zipcode
 }).Where(i=>i.IsPrimary==true);
```

if `resultStaffGua` count `0`, I need one record from `resultStaffGua`. Thank you

Comment: What `result`?  What `parentList`?  Apart from that I don't understand the question

Comment: @MickyD - See my update question.

Comment: @CGPA6.4, did u try below answer by JohnWu?

Comment: @er-shoaib -John answer looks straight forward. That I could have thought. I am willing to do in a single line. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if result count 0, I need one record from parentList.

Sometimes the obvious solution is the best. Why not add this after your code?

```
if (resultStaffGua.Count() == 0) 
{
    resultStaffGua = parentList.First();  
}
```

If you want to be "clever" and do it all in one line (and I guess it would save a DB transaction too possibly) you could exchange your `Where` for an `OrderBy` and a `Take`.

So instead of:

```
).Where(i=>i.IsPrimary==true);
```

You could do:

```
).OrderBy( i => i.IsPrimary ? 0 : 1 ).Take(1);
```

This will prioritize any record that has an `IsPrimary` set to true, but it'll get one record regardless of whether any match.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I could have think of it but I wanted solution so than I can do it in a single line. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your intent is to retrieve one single record (there's at most one record with `IsPrimary==true`):

```
var query = (from s in...); //The whole query except the "where"
var resultStaffGua = query.SingleOrDefault(i=>i.IsPrimary==true) ?? query.First();
```

Otherwise, if the query could actually return more than one result:

```
var query = (from s in...);
var resultStaffGua = query.Where(i=>i.IsPrimary==true);
if(resultStaffGua.Count() == 0) resultStaffGua = new[] { query.First(); }
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Can't I do it in a single line so that I need need to take extra `query` variable. Result directly would come in `resultStaffGua`